# Copy column with mathematic SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server. I have column with value of product, now I want to add column value + tax (tax = 10% value) on the same table. Any suggestion how to do this the fastest way or should I insert 1 by 1? Can I just copy value column and add some mathematics ? If I can do that can someone show how it work? Thanks.

Comment: Run `Update` query with `Self join` to update the data.

Comment: You might not want to add such a computed column at all, since the tax rate could change at some point.

Answer (score 0):

If the tax is always the same, you can use a computed column:

```
alter t add value_plus_tax as (value * 1.1);
```

This calculates the value whenever you need it.  Otherwise, you should add the column explicitly and update it:

```
alter t add value_plus_tax decimal(10, 2); -- or whatever

update t
    set value_plus_tax = value * 1.1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your tax rate can change, you can store the rate in a separate table and use a view that joins the two tables to retrieve the data...

```
CREATE TABLE TaxRate (
    [Percent] TINYINT
)

GO

CREATE VIEW ValuesWithTax AS
SELECT *, [Value] * [Percent] / 100 ValueWithTax FROM [Values]
CROSS JOIN TaxRate
```

Answer (score 0):

If tax rate is not a fix value, you can add a column to save tax rate and a computed column to save total value

```
ALTER TABLE table1 add tax_rate decimal(19,4) DEFAULT(0.1) WITH VALUES
ALTER TABLE table1 add toatal_value as ([value](1+tax_rate))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add computed column like (having all calculation).

Ie : Below example i have considered sum of value and tax column you can do any calculation (Make sure the calculation should not throw exception consider boundary condition )  .

```
       ALTER TABLE dbo.tableName ADD RetailValue AS (value+tax );
```

you can make it persisted computed column too.